# How to Display 3D View in Asp.net C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a STP file (take any file format which stores information to show object in 3D Format). In ASP.NET , C# application, i want to display this as a 3D View on my website. What are the API's available for the same. Preferably a freeware or best with price in paid versions.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it.

http://www.3dvieweronline.com/

Load your assembly here and get the IFrame code for the assembly.
Integrate this IFrame into your code and thus you have the 3D View available on your site.

Now, Another Question follows this..

Is this the only tool or way to display the image.
I have a few more, R&D in progress..  Will update more details soon..

If anyone can guide me on this, its really great..

Thanks..